# Return success with parameter in php/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I need to adjust send.php file so that it returns success with parameter and check $json['success'] == 'success'. Then show popup with a "success" message (look at the HIDDEN section, #modal_success) after form submit.

At this point, the data from all contact forms is sent to my email, but the popup with the "success" message won't show up. Could you please help me. Thank you

This is JavaScript file

```
// MODAL

$('.modalshow').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var 
    $href = $(this).attr('href'),
    $form = $(this).attr('data-form');
    if($form) {
        $($href).find('input[name="form"]').val($form);
    }

    $.fancybox.open({
        src  : $href,
        type : 'inline',
        afterLoad : function() {
            window.quizSlider.update();
        }
    });
})
$(document).on('click', '.fmodal', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.fancybox.open( $($href+' a'), {});
})  
    // # MODAL

// FORM SUBMIT

$('.form').on('submit', function () {
  var
    $form = $(this),
    $name = $form.find('input[name="name"]'),
    $phone = $form.find('input[name="phone"]'),
    $email = $form.find('input[name="email"]'),
    $agree = $form.find('input[name="agree"]:checked'),
    $rv_email = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/,
    $error = false;

  if ($form.hasClass('form__file')) {
    var $data = new FormData();
    if ($name.length) {
      $data.append('name', $name.val());
    }
    if ($phone.length) {
      $data.append('phone', $phone.val());
    }
    if ($email.length) {
      $data.append('email', $email.val());
    }
  } else {
    var $data = $form.serialize();
  }


  if ($form.find('input[name="agree"]').length && !$agree.length) {
    $form.find('.agree__cont').addClass('invalid');
    $error = true;
  } else {
    $form.find('.agree__cont').removeClass('invalid');
  }

  if ($name.length) {
    if ($name.val().length < 3) {
      $name.addClass('invalid');
      $error = true;
    } else {
      $name.removeClass('invalid');
    }
  }
  if ($phone.length) {
    if ($phone.val().length < 1) {
      $phone.addClass('invalid');
      $error = true;
    } else {
      $phone.removeClass('invalid');
    }
  }
  if ($email.length) {
    if ($email.val().length < 1 || !$rv_email.test($email.val())) {
      $email.addClass('invalid');
      $error = true;
    } else {
      $email.removeClass('invalid');
    }
  }

  if ($error) {
    return false;
  } else {
    if ($form.hasClass('form__file')) {
      if ($form.find('input[name="file"]').length) {
        $data.append("file", $form.find('input[name="file"]')[0].files[0]);
      }
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./send.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function ($json) {

        },
        success: function ($json) {
          if ($json['success']) {

            $instance = $.fancybox.getInstance();
            if ($instance) { $instance.close(); }
            $.fancybox.open({
              src: $('#modal_success'),
              type: 'inline'
            });
          }
        },
        error: function (json) {
          console.log(json);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./send.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $data,
        beforeSend: function ($json) {

        },
        success: function ($json) {
          if ($json['success']) {

            $instance = $.fancybox.getInstance();
            if ($instance) { $instance.close(); }
            $.fancybox.open({
              src: $('#modal_success'),
              type: 'inline'
            });
          }
        },
        error: function (json) {
          console.log(json);
        }
      });
    }

  }
  return false;
})
        // # FORM SUBMIT
```

This is the send.php file

```
<?php
$subject = "New request"; 
$message = "Name: ".$_POST['name']."<br>";
$message .= "E-mail: ".$_POST['email']."<br>"; 
$message .= "Phone: ".$_POST['phone']."<br>";
$message .= "Form: ".$_POST['form']."<br>"; 
$message .= "Where: ".$_POST['where']."<br>";
$message .= "Square: ".$_POST['square']."<br>"; 
$message .= "Price: ".$_POST['price']."<br>"; 
$message .= "When: ".$_POST['when']."<br>"; 
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$success = mail("email@email.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
echo $success;
?>
```

This is HTML part on the same page where contact forms are

```
<!-- HIDDEN -->

<div id="modal_success" class="modal__item success__modal">
  <div class="modal__title">Thank you! Your request has been sent!</div>
  <div class="success__text">we will contact you shortly</div>
</div>

<!-- # HIDDEN -->
```

Comment: You are using the correct way of doing this. Try `concole.log($json)` in your success callback. then you can easy see the results you are getting

Comment: PHP mail function returns true or false. You are checking for a non existing value $json['success'].

Comment: i'd be very greatful if someone provided me with a piece of code to make it work

Comment: Stackoverflow is more about guidance to solve it yourself. I could be wrong, but your code looks like a copy paste result from combining javascript and PHP code snippets.